# Retrieve only own attributes with vars()

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes

In python, `vars()` retrieves all attributes of an object. For instances of classes that derive from other classes, is there a convenient way to filter out the 'inherited' attributes? My purpose for doing so is to define the `__eq__` comparison on just own attributes.

Based on my understanding, those attributes aren't inherited but directly exist in the instance from calls to `super().__init__()` so there wouldn't be a built-in separation mechanism.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0


class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.b = 1


derived = Derived()

# results in {'a': 0, 'b': 1}
# how can I make this return {'b': 1}?
print(vars(derived))
```

My current solution works but it requires defining it for each class:

```
class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pre_init_attrs = set(vars(self).keys())
        # own init
        self.b = 1

        # process own init
        post_init_attrs = set(vars(self).keys())
        self._own_attrs = post_init_attrs.difference(pre_init_attrs)

    def vars(self):
        return {key: self.__dict__[key] for key in self._own_attrs}
```

Is there a way of accomplishing this with a decorator or metaclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for doesn't really make sense with the way classes work in Python.

`vars` already *does* filter out inherited attributes from base classes.

But `self.a` isn't inherited. It's explicitly added to your `self` instance, because your `__init__` explicitly calls `super().__init__()`. There's really nothing special about that call—if your `__init__` called `self.addx()` and a `Derived.addx` method did a `self.x = 0`, it would work exactly the same way as what you're doing here.

You could write a decorator to do what you're trying to do, but maybe it's better to take a step back.

Why not store the list of fields you expect each class to provide as part of the class?

Or, since you seem to be trying to simulate something more like Java-style classes, where the set of attributes is fixed per class, why not just use `@dataclass` (or, if you need pre-3.7 compatibility or extra features, the third-party `@attr.s`)? That automatically takes care of keeping track of which fields belong to which class, and a whole lot of other things along with it.

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
>>> 
>>>> @dataclass
... class Base:
...     a: int = 0
... 
>>> @dataclass
... class Derived(Base):
...     b: int = 1
...
>>> derived = Derived()
>>> derived
Derived(a=0, b=1)
>>> def ownfields(obj):
...     fs = fields(obj)
...     for base in type(obj).__bases__:
...         basefs = set(fields(base))
...         fs = [f for f in fs if f not in basefs]
...     return fs
...
>>> ownfields(derived)
[Field(name='b',type=<class 'int'>,default=1,default_factory=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x10571ca58>,init=True,repr=True,hash=None,compare=True,metadata=mappingproxy({}),_field_type=_FIELD)]
>>> def ownvars(obj):
...     return {field.name: getattr(obj, field.name) for field in ownfields(obj)}
...
>>> ownvars(derived)
{'b': 1}
```

(With `attrs` instead of `dataclasses`, you can do effectively the same thing—but it might be clearer to write it as `attr.asdict` with a `filter` param to blacklist the base classes' fields.)

The code above allows for multiple inheritance of `dataclass` types, but not multiple inheritance of both `dataclass` and non-`dataclass`. If you want that, just add a `try` to `ownfields`:

```
>>> def ownfields(obj):
...     fs = fields(obj)
...     for base in type(obj).__bases__:
...         try:
...             basefs = set(fields(base))
...         except TypeError:
...             pass
...         else:
...             fs = [f for f in fs if f not in basefs]
...     return fs
```

This still doesn't work if, e.g., you inherit from multiple classes that aren't dataclasses themselves but both inherit from dataclasses in a diamond pattern. I'm not sure what the intended behavior would be in that case. Probably just follow `type(obj).mro()[1:]`? That won't be any more surprising than anything else, and it seems like the most consistent parallel to lookup…

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at attrs; I heard about dataclasses but the code base is pre 3.7. Note that I already knew the 'inherited' attributes are not inherited but defined on the derived instance directly. I mentioned 'inherited' attributes (with quotation) as a way to refer to those attributes instead of "attributes defined from calls to base initializers in the derived instance"

Comment: @LemonPi Right; the point is that keeping track of the attributes is probably a better solution than figuring them out dynamically, at least if you can take further advantage of the same information by using something like `@dataclass` or `@attr.s` or `__slots__`, which I think you can in this case.